# How to compose alpha information on a render result with transparency?

Tags: transparency, compositing-nodes

I would like to compose in Blender a very simple result (actually simple...)
Attached you see what I have.

How to do this in Blender?!

Thank you in advance.

Chris

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think the Alpha Over node will do what you want?  Here are some quick results:

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you! I was shure I've tested this combination already... but no matter.